# jquery set html with effect

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div which is already displaying some html.  I'd like to replace the contents of the div with some different html.  However, I'd like the transition to have an effect, such as a fade-in.

I've tried this:

```
$('#mydiv').html('Some new text').fadeIn(1500);
```

but the transition happens immediately, with no fade effect.  Can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#mydiv').hide().html('Some new text').fadeIn(1500);
```